# How to check if for loop is on the last element of an iterator?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to find a way of checking if I am on the last element of an iterator in a for loop without using .clone(); currently I'm doing this:

```
let sentence = "The quick brown fox.";
let words = sentence.split(' ');
let last = words.clone().last().unwrap();
 
for word in words {
    if word == last {
        print!("{}", word);
    }
}
```

I've also tried using .collect() on the iterator, but this requires that I use .iter().enumerate() to check for the last index, which seems unnecessarily complicated to me:

```
let sentence = "The quick brown fox.";
let words: Vec<&str> = sentence.split(' ').collect();
 
for (i, word) in words.iter().enumerate() {
    if i == words.len() - 1 {
        print!("{}", word);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in a more succinct way, perhaps just using the original iterator?

Comment: BTW using  `enumerate` is perfectly appropriate when you need the index. There's no reason to avoid it.

Comment: @DenysSéguret It just seemed redundant to me that I have to convert the iterator to a vector, then I convert it back to an iterator again to get the index

Comment: This conversion to vec is a legit concern yes. In the general case of the last iterator's item, you can find below Masklinn's answer which elegantly buffer the next element. In your exact case you have mine which is simpler and more efficient. But in the very general case of really needing the index, use `enumerate`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Convert your iterator to a [`Peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html).

This will require desugaring the iteration to a `while let`, but if during the iteration [`peek()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html#method.peek) returns `None` you're on the last iteration:

```
let mut it = sentence.split(' ').peekable();
while let Some(word) = it.next()  {
    if it.peek().is_none() {
        println!("{}", word);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0c7dd2028052471bd62f1821fef7d530).

Answer (score 7):

For the general case of finite iterators, if you want to get the last item, you can, as suggests @Masklinn (see their answer), convert to a `Peekable` which will buffer so it always knows the next element.

In your precise case, when you just want to print the last word and don't care about the other ones, there *is* a much cheaper solution because splitting on a character implements `DoubleEndedIterator`.

So it's easy to get the last word, you don't have to collect the whole split nor to enumerate. It's also fast as the string will be searched from the end and nothing will be copied.

So you can do

```rust
let last_word = sentence
    .split(' ').rev().next().unwrap(); // SAFETY: there's always at least one word
```

Comment: There is a totally general solution via `peekable` (though of course the results may be unexpected if fed an infinite iterator).

Answer (score 4):

You could take advantage of the [`Iterator::map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) iterator adaptor for achieving a more convenient usage:

```
let sentence = "The quick brown fox.";
let words: Vec<&str> = sentence.split(' ').collect();

for (word, is_last_element) in words.iter().enumerate()
  .map(|(i, w)| (w, i == words.len() - 1))
{
   if is_last_element {
      println!("{}", word);
   }
}
```

This way, instead of having to deal with the index in the body of the loop, you just focus on whether or not the given element in a particular iteration is the last one.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be as performant as the other answers, but this is cleaner - you can use `itertools`'s [`with_position()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.with_position):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

let sentence = "The quick brown fox.";
let words = sentence.split(' ');

for word in words.with_position() {
    if let itertools::Position::Last(word) | itertools::Position::Only(word) = word {
        print!("{}", word);
    }
}
```

You can also check for other conditions, such as first, middle etc..

Comment: This is the best answer. It also lets you check if the item is the first element. It uses `Peekable` under the hood so I don't think it will really be any slower than any of the other answers.

Comment: The only slightly annoying this is you need to check for `Only` too, and there's no `is_first` or `is_last` which checks for both for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to @Masklinn 's answer.

I have used a trait to make it a little more readable.

The code allows `it.peek().is_none()` to be written as `it.is_last()`.

```rust
trait IterEndPeek {
    fn is_last(&mut self) -> bool;
}

impl<I: Iterator> IterEndPeek for  std::iter::Peekable<I> {
    fn is_last(&mut self) -> bool {
        self.peek().is_none()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sentence = "The quick brown fox.";
    let mut it = sentence.split(' ').peekable();
    while let Some(word) = it.next()  {
        if it.is_last() {
            println!("last {}", word);
        } else {
            println!("- {}", word);
        }
    }
}
```